# How to use .then or await inside a for loop in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a Nodejs function which registers for an event to get the data and do some manipulations and then insert in to an Elastic DB. My code looks like below.

```
async function callB() {
    var block_reg = channel_event_hub.registerBlockEvent((block) => {
        const transactionArray = block.data.data;

        for (const trans of transactionArray) {
            var writeSet = trans.payload.data.actions[0]

            for (const writes of writeSet) {
                var updatefunc = validateVlaues(writeSet);

                updatefunc.then(function (result) {
                    EP.push(numberjson);
                    EP.push(result);
                })
            }
        }

        console.log("EP ", EP.length); // Executing even before .then

        elasticClient.bulk({
            index: 'indexdata',
            type: '_doc',
            body: EP,
        }
      }, (error) => {
    });
}
```

Please help me with this. Or how can I use `await` in this scenario. Function is an `async` function, but inside `Blockevent` how can i use `await` . Im stuck with this for long time. Can anybody suggest me how to preoceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're inside a callback. You must make the callback `async`.

```
async function callB() {
                                                   // here
 var block_reg = channel_event_hub.registerBlockEvent(async (block) => {
     const transactionArray = block.data.data;
     ...
```

Then you can await the Promise:

```
const result = await updatefunc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), [while](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while), etc loop type along with [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) as long as the function is an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

For example, if you're calling a function that reads data from an api that returns a Promise, you can await the result within the loop and everything will work as you expect.

The await syntax is also more readable then the .then syntax IMHO.

```js
// function reading user details from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
async function getDataFromApi(userId) {
    return await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${userId}`)
        .then(response => response.json());
}


// Read results from all ids
async function getAllDataFromApi() {
    let ids = [1,2,3];
    for(let id of ids) {
        console.log(`Getting data from api for user id ${id}...`);
        let result = await getDataFromApi(id);
        console.log(`Result from api for user id ${id}:`, result);
    }

}

getAllDataFromApi();
```